# Why does declaring a command in-document produce horizontal space?

Tags: spacing, macros

I'm really confused about why there is some extra horizontal space that appears before the second "Test" on my second line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Test Test

Test \newcommand{\foo}{} Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have a space before the `\newcommand` and before the final `Test`, both of which are actualized.  If you had two consecutive spaces, it would be treated as a single space, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Okay, so eliminating the space cures this, but makes the code less readable.  Is there a solution to that?

Comment: @AFeldman After playing around, it seems like one possibility is to keep the space before `\newcommand{\foo}{}`, but write a `%` immediately afterwards and then put the second `Test` on the next line of code. It seems more readable to me, at least.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as pointed out by Steven Segletes, only consecutive spaces are compressed
into a single space, so a `\newcommand` in the middle of text, with a
space on either side, will result in a wider space in the output.

if you are looking for readability in the source file, you can avoid the
spacy output at the cost of more lines in the source:

```
Test
\newcommand{\foo}{}%
Test
```

the same spacy result is often caused by inserting multiple `\index` entries for the same text in a source file, and can be solved in the
same way:

```
some text
\index{index item}%
\index{item to be indexed}%
item to be indexed
```

i know you probably haven't reached that problem yet, but it's a good
idea to learn good habits early.